# Show that weighted average of a function involving expected values is not equal to the function of the weighted average

Tags: real-analysis, probability

How can I show that, given $w_j$ sum to $1$

$$\sum_{j=1}^n w_j \frac{a}{E(x_j)+b}\ne \frac{a}{E(\sum_{j=1}^n w_j x_j)+b}$$

unless $x_j=x_k \forall j,k \\$ where a and b are constants, $x_j$ are arbitrary R.V.'s? I see some similarity to Jensen's inequality but I'm not sure how to approach that.

Thanks!

Comment: if $w_j$ would sum up to $1$ , then indeed it is Jensen...do they?

Comment: Yes, how would you show the function is strictly convex/concave though. Also I'm a bit confused on the specifics of what I would be applying it to. Are you thinking of a new discrete random variable with discrete probabilities at $w_1$, $w_2$, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you want to prove that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_jf(X_j)\geq (\text{or} \leq ? ) ~f(\sum_{i=1}^n \omega_jX_j)$$

for all $n$, with $\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_j=1$, $X_1,\dots,X_n$ random variables and

$$f(X):=\frac{a}{E[X]+b}.$$

What can you say about $f$?

Comment: Thanks, it's nonlinear... then I can't apply Jensen's per say but looking at it's proof gives me the idea of how to do it.

Comment: Actually I should probably state over x>b it is strictly concave. (I am only concerned about X>b)